# DTM data element custom script not accepting regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, adobe

My first post here. I am attempting to strip all but the numeric characters from a ClassName (IDHeader) that passes as "Welcome 123456 | Logout".

I have tested the following script on JSfiddle, it works perfectly. But when I apply it to the custom script field of a new data element in DTM it fails.

```
var text = $('.IDHeader').text();
var res = text.replace(/Welcome | \W Logout/g, '');
```

Is the regex not accepted in custom scripts for data elements in DTM?? It is the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "Welcome 123456 | Logout";
var rexp = new RegExp(/Welcome | \W Logout/g);
str = str.replace(rexp, "");
alert(str);
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. I stared at the screen for too long on that one.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)